# a way to abstract the success/failure of a subprocess

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msmq

I'm processing messages from an MSMQ.

For each message there are ten steps such as :

1. VerifyDates
2. VerifyPatientInformation
3. VerifyClinicalInformation

If there is a failure in any one of the three steps, I would like to throw out the message.

Can someone point to a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) example demonstrating this principal? I'm not sure how to structure my classes.

For example

```
public class VerifyDates()
{
    private validateSomething ValidateSomething();

    public VerifyDates()
    {
        validateSomething = new ValidateSomething();
    }

    public bool Verify()
    {
        validateSomething.IsValid();
    }

}
```

Assuming that `VerifyDates()` is part of my processing logic, should I be adding a public field to the class **bool Flag** that returns whether or not to continue processing?

Perhaps I should add an Interface **IHasFlag** where every class that is used within my processing logic has a Flag that I check at the end to see whether or not to continue message processing?

Processing messages would go something like this

```
public void ProcessMessages()
{
  var verifyDates = new VerifyDates();
  if(!verifyDates.IsValid)
  {
    return;
  }
  //continue processing
  //but every step of the process I would need to check IsValid for that specific class
}
```

**How do you abstract the success/failure of every step within a sequential process?**

Answer (score 2):

You could use a fluent API. Something similar to the following:

```
public interface IFluentValidation<T>
{
     bool IsValid { get; }
     T ObjectToValidate { get; }
}

internal class FluentValidation<T>: IFluentValidation<T>
{
    public bool IsValid { get; }
    public T ObjectToValidate { get; }

    public FluentValidation(bool isValid, T target)
    {
        Debug.Assert(target != null);
        IsValid = isValid;
        ObjectToValidate = target;
    }
}
```

And now build the following extension methods:

```
public static IFluentValidation<T> ValidateBy<T>(this T target, Predicate<T> validator)
{
     if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name(target));
     if (validator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name(validator));

     if (validator(target))
        return new FluentValidation<T>(true, target);

     return new FluentValidation<T>(false, target);
}

public static IFluentValidation<T> AndBy<T>(this IFluentValidation<T> target, Predicate<T> validator)
{
     if (validator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(name(validator));

     if (!target.IsValid)
        return target;

     if (validator(target.ObjectToValidate)
        return target;

     return new FluentValidation<T>(false, target.ObjectToValidate);
}
```

Implementing an `OrBy` is trivial as a `AndFinallyBy` if you want to return the validated object and not a `IFluentValidation<T>`.

And you would use it like this:

```
 var validated = myObject.ValidateBy(t => //whatever needs to checked t.ObjectToValidate.DateIsValid)
                         .ThenBy(t => ... //whatever needs to be checked t. ObjectToValidate.PatientIsValid)
                         .ThenBy(t => ... //t.ObjectToValidate .ClinicalInformationIsValid)
                         .IsValid;
```

You can also embellish this a little more and add optional custom error messages in each validation step; `public static IFluentValidation<T> AndBy<T>(this IFluentValidation<T> target, Predicate<T> validator, Func<T, string> failureMessageProvider = null)` and add the corresponding property `string ValidationFailedMessage { get; }` to `IFluentValidation`

Comment: thank you very much can you demonstrate a usage of this api

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' whoops, stupid syntactic mistakes. It should work now, I'm typing on my phone so things can have minor mistakes.

Comment: impressive phone typing!! can you please show a simple usage?